# Can persona photos be watermarked shutterstock images or illustrations?

Tags: personas, portfolio

I am a new UX Designer building my first portfolio. I have a project where I have personas "photos" as a cute illustration, in which some have watermarks and others don't.

Here are my two main questions:

1. Can personas be an illustration of a person?
2. Is it unprofessional to have a watermark on my image for a persona?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I am not really sure about the relevance of this question to UX design, but I'll approach it specifically from the of creating personas as an artefact. Whether it applies to projects or portfolios is basically dependent on the requirements of the project or the purpose of the portfolios. So to your questions:

> Can personas be an illustration of a person?

There is no requirement for personas to be a photo or an illustration, but it can be designed to either give people a more specific/realistic impression of the persona if you use a photo, or more abstract if you use a generic type of illustration.

> Is it unprofessional to have a watermark on my image for a persona?

If you are using a stock image with a watermark on portfolio work, it might give the appearance that some of the content might also be copy and pasted rather than your own work.

If you are applying a watermark on an image in your portfolio work to prevent other people from copying and pasting it, then it probably needs to be explained to prevent any confusions or misunderstanding about it.

It probably is better to be consistent in the use and selection of your images, rather than for some to have watermarks and others to not have any.